# Is it possible to install the unofficial Froyo on a Samsung I5800XXJG3 android phone?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, samsung-galaxy-apollo

I know the official Froyo has not been released, but I see here that you can Install it on samsung phones: http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-lite/251507-update-android-2-1-eclair-2-2-froyo-your-samsung-gt-i5800.html
But there it mentions

I5800XXJPF
I5800XXJPB

but does not mention
I5800XXJP3

so is it possible, if so, how?

Comment: What is "I5800XXJP3"?  What is it referring to?  Phone model? Firmware?

Comment: Base firmware as far as I know, see the link.

Comment: Also the battery drainage increased significantly when calling, It can be balanced out by tapping & holding on the home screen (desktop/main screen) and then going to Widgets > Power tools and just removing some of the things that drain power, like brightness, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that It is possible with the I5800XXJPF update with the 4 (out of 5) separate files and the Odin multi downloader tool.

here are the instructions of how to [update 2.1 Eclair to 2.2 Froyo](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-lite/251507-update-android-2-1-eclair-2-2-froyo-your-samsung-gt-i5800.html).